# Retrieve multiple jQuery append data to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, append

I have an input that is appended by jQuery when the "Add another account" button is clicked. Because they all have the same name, only one result is retrieved in JSON, which is the last result "3123213".

I'm trying to get all the results from the input field in JSON like : **accountsToLink":[
"3453453453",
"3543453453",
"5345345345"
]**
, but couldn't find a way to do it with jQuery append.

Please help!

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 input_fields_wrap">
<input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" id="inputAccountNumber" name="accountsToLink" placeholder="9102031012" maxlength="10" required>
<div class="input-group-append">
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button"><strong>x</strong></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center mt-4">
<button class="btn-outlined add_field_button">Add another account</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-group mt-3 additional-acc-number"><input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" name="accountsToLink" placeholder="9102031012" maxlength="10"><div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger remove_field" type="button"><strong>x</strong></button></div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
</script>
```

[image: jquery append input]

Comment: How does your json gets generated ? Are you using ajax ? Please elaborate more and add relevant code as well.

Comment: Hi, I am using exactly this method from https://simonplend.com/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-to-your-api/ . Sorry that I am not sure what method is that called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` to loop through your inputs which are generated dynamically and then add its value inside `JSON Array` using `.push($(this).val())` where `$(this).val()` is value of input box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count

  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click

    e.preventDefault();

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed

      x++; //text box increment
      //added inputs class inside div
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-group mt-3  inputs additional-acc-number"><input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" name="accountsToLink" placeholder="9102031012" maxlength="10"><div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger remove_field" type="button"><strong>x</strong></button></div></div>'); //add input box

    }

  });



  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();

    x--;

  });



  $("#sendme").click(function() {
    var acc_main = {} //create object
    acc_main["accountsToLink"] = new Array //create array
    $(".inputs > input[name=accountsToLink] ").each(function() {
      acc_main["accountsToLink"].push($(this).val()) //push value in array
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(acc_main))
    //your ajax call here /...

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added inputs class-->
<div class="input-group mb-3 inputs input_fields_wrap">

  <input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" id="inputAccountNumber" name="accountsToLink" placeholder="9102031012" maxlength="10" required>

  <div class="input-group-append">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button"><strong>x</strong></button>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="text-center mt-4">

  <button class="btn-outlined add_field_button">Add another account</button>

</div>

<button id="sendme">SEnd me</button>
```

***Update 1*** :

As you need to merge this json with the `formData` you just need to make changes here :

```
async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
    const plainFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    plainFormData["accountsToLink"] = new Array //create array
    $("input[name=accountsToLink] ").each(function() {
      plainFormData["accountsToLink"].push($(this).val()) //push value in array
    })
    console.log(plainFormData)
    //everthing same..
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer did not work straight away but changing your $(".inputs > input[name=accountsToLink] ") to $( "input[name=accountsToLink]" ) kind of does the trick.

Can I ask how would you usually do to post it to JSON so that I can see the JSON results in the Network>Headers?

Comment: https://simonplend.com/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-to-your-api/
This is the method that I am using to get form post request, but this added input field feels separated from the form so I'm not very sure how to 'merge' them together.

Comment: Updated my answer have a look . You just need to use `plainFormData` and add create new key using it and push value to same . Let me know if that doesn't work .

Comment: Is this code still placed at the same place replacing the $("#sendme").click(function() { ?

Comment: No move it inside `postFormDataAsJson` function because when you click on submit button this values  also need to be send .My code is just for demo you need to make changes according to your requirement.

Comment: Alright, moved it there but there is an error in the console saying formDataJsonString is not defined. 
This is the script code there:
https://jsfiddle.net/xczt463k/

Can't thank you enough for looking at it for me! :)

Comment: You forgot this line `const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);` check that link its there .:) .Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c7ehpoq3/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! I have been putting the const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData); at the wrong place! 

Now it is working, THANKS A LOT Swati, you really saved a lot of my time.